# If $ 0 \le t \lt 1$ then, $\lim\limits_{R \uparrow \infty}\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{-R\sin\theta}R^t\text d\theta = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, fourier-transform

**If** $ 0 \le t \lt 1$ then, $$\lim\limits_{R \uparrow \infty}\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{-R\sin\theta}R^t\,\text d\theta = 0$$

I'm not sure how to solve this, I thought about starting to show that $ 0 \le \sin\theta \le \pi/2$, then $ 0 \le \sin\theta \le 2\theta/\pi$. But I'm still not sure how to continue from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the fact that $\sin(\pi -\theta)=\sin \,\theta$ you can see that $\int_{\pi /2}^{\pi} e^{-R\sin\, \theta} R^{t}\text d\theta =\int_{0}^{\pi /2} e^{-R\sin\, \theta} R^{t}\text d\theta$. On $(0, \pi/2)$ we have $\sin\, \theta \geq \frac 2 {\pi} \theta$. Can you complete the argument now?

Comment: Like that:
$\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} e^{-R\sin\theta}R^td\theta\leq\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} e^{-\frac{2R}{\pi}\theta}R^td\theta =\lim_{R\to\infty}\frac{\pi}{2R}(1-e^{-R})R^t =0$

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Wow, thank you. :)

Comment: This also holds for integral from $0$ to $\pi$ right?

Comment: $\sin \theta \geq \frac 2 {\pi} \theta$ is not true on $(0, \pi)$. Let $\theta $ tend to $\pi$ to get a contradiction. @IlanAizelmanWS

Comment: I see, so how can it be generalized to $\lim\limits_{R \uparrow \infty}\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{-R\sin\theta}R^t\,d\theta = 0$?

Comment: Oh I can just sum the integrals from $\pi /2$ to $\pi$ and from $0$ to $\pi /2$ which will be still zero because they're equal :)

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer the integral from $\pi/2$ to $\pi$ equals integral from $0$ to $\pi /2$. So integral from $0$ to $\pi$ is twice the integral form $0$ to $\pi /2$. So it is enough to show that integral from $0$ to $\pi /2$ tends to $0$.

Comment: Right, thank you :)